# an example of tangent equation calculation, from a book, that I do not understand

Tags: derivatives, tangent-line

I am in trouble with an example of an equation of a tangent from a book.
Here's what my book is writing (in french) :

[image]

I translate it (summarizing a bit) : take a T(X,Y) point on the tangent,
the slope between M and T is $\frac{Y - f(x_{0})}{X - x_{0}}$

This slope is also the derived number on M, $f'(x_{0})$ : $\frac{Y - f(x_{0})}{X - x_{0}} = f'(x_{0})$

The relationship between the coordinates (X,Y) of T are thus
$Y - f(x_{0}) = f'(x_{0}).(X - x_{0})$

### But here is the sample given, that troubles me :

What the equation of the tangent in $\mathbf{x_{0} = 2}$ to the parabole of equation $\mathbf{y = x^2}$ ?

[image]
(*this drawing isn't from the author, it's mine, to figure what is $y = x^2$, and what $x_{0} = 2$ or $x_{0} = 3$ would then mean*)

On $x_{0} = 3, y_{0} = 9$ ; the derivative being $y' = 2x$, we have $y_{0}' = 6$

1. First question : why does the author assign $x_{0} = 3$
   if he said he is looking for $x_{0} = 2$ the line just before?
   reassigning an $x_{0}$ looks strange to me.

According to 8.7, the equation **to the tangent** on $x_{0} = 2$

2. Here, $x_{0}$ returns to its previous assignment : $x_{0} = 2$...

to the parabole is :
$Y - 9 = 6(X - 3)$ or $Y = 6X - 9$

It's very troublesome.

Especially because when I check with M(2,4),
$y_{m} = 6x_{m} - 9$ with $x_{m}=2$ gives $y_{m} = 6 \times 2 - 9 = 12 - 9 = 3$
which is not on the curve, and I am supposed to be on the tangent equation.

3. If with $y = x^2 $ M has for coordinates M(2,4),
   why this tangent equation is returning me a point of coordinates (2, 3) for it?

Comment: For what it's worth, I share your confusion.  In the previous example, the point labeled $M$ referred to $(x_0,y_0)$, where the slope ($M$) was computed as $f'(x_0)$.  In the example that you (**and I**) are confused about, I would expect that the slope would be computed as $f'(2) = 4.$  This is inconsistent with what the author is saying.  Assuming that I have not misunderstood the intent of the author's *first example*, my only explanation is that this portion of the text is **negligently written**, and that not all Mathematicians are competent Math writers.

Comment: @user2661923 the explanation was given in my answer in french, which is now translated in english.

Comment: Questions about textbook typos are on topic here, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28615/207316 It may help future readers if you mention which textbook this example comes from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'auteur a fait 2 fois la même coquille. Remplace simplement ses deux "$x_{0} = 2
$" par  "$x_{0} =3
$".

---

The author did twice the same typo.
Only replace the two "$x_{0} = 2$"'s by "$x_{0} = 3$".

Comment: I disagree with your interpretation of the author's mistake.  In the first image, $(x_0,y_0)$ is the point on the graph labeled $M$.  This is **very sensible**, as it signifies that the slope at that point on the graph is what determines the (real value) $M$.  This is inconsistent with the 2nd graph, since the $M$ appears at $(2,4)$.  For the 2nd graph, labeling $(3,9)$ as $(x_0,y_0)$ leaves the author's presentation as **negligent**.

Comment: The answer was not “valuable” to a large number of users, i.e. those that do not speak French. Users should not, as a general rule of thumb, be required to refer to outside sources (such as Google Translate in this case) to understand and benefit from the resources on this website. I will not comment on the correctness of this answer as I have not analysed the question properly, but if it is indeed correct, then the answer is now valuable to a larger group of users after the edit. Footnote: I have removed my downvote.

Comment: I do not have the required moderator capacities to review any votes for deletion, but I can tell you that I have since retracted my flag that I had raised. I’ll shortly delete these comments once you acknowledge them by upvoting on the last comment as these are irrelevant now.

Comment: @user2661923 *Yes* the author is "negligent" since he made twice the same typo. But *no*, you can't charge him for the 2nd graph nor for writing "$x_0=3,y_0=9$" (in the question, outside the graph): both are due to the OP (Marc Le Bihan).