# Evaluating the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac {x^5+\pi x^4+e}{x^5+ex^4+\pi}\right)^x$

Tags: calculus, limits

How can I evaluate the following limit?
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac {x^5+\pi x^4+e}{x^5+ex^4+\pi}\right)^x$$

To solve this limit, I divided the numerator and denominator by $x^5$ and I got

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac {1+\frac {1}{x}\pi+\frac {1}{x^5}e}{1+\frac {1}{x}e+\frac {1}{x^5}\pi}\right)^x$$

But I realized when $x\to\infty$  the expression is still indeterminate.

I tried changing the $x=\frac {1}{y}$ variable to be able to apply Lophital's rule, but I couldn't get a useful result.

Answer (score 2):

The limit is $e^{\pi-e},$ because $A^x=e^{x\ln A}$ ($\forall A>0$) and as $x\to\infty,$
$$\begin{align}x\ln\frac {1+\frac\pi x+o(1/x)}{1+\frac ex+o(1/x)}&=x\Big(\ln(1+\pi/x+o(1/x))-\ln(1+e/x+o(1/x))\Big)\\&=x\Big((\pi/x+o(1/x))-(e/x+o(1/x))\Big)\\&=x\left(\frac{\pi-e}x+o(1/x)\right)\\&\to\pi-e.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Я не понимаю, почему $\ln\frac {1+\frac\pi x+o(1/x)}{1+\frac ex+o(1/x)}=\left(\frac\pi x-\frac ex+o(1/x)\right)$. Объясните, пожалуйста. Известно, что $\ln\frac{a}{b}=\left(\ln(a)-\ln(b)\right)$.

Comment: Please, @VadimChernetsov [I already asked you to write in english](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4598490/).

Comment: Уважаемая Анна, Вы не объяснили, почему $\ln(1+\pi/x+o(1/x))=(\pi/x+o(1/x))$? Объясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: @AnneBauval This site does not have a policy requiring anyone to interact in English.  If you don't want to run the comment through Google translate, you are free to ignore it and move on.

Comment: I remember [having been strongly urged on this site to stop interacting in French](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4537258) : "[Your] answer was not “valuable” to a large number of users, i.e. those that do not speak French. Users should not, as a general rule of thumb, be required to refer to outside sources (such as Google Translate in this case) to understand and benefit from the resources on this website.". And Vadim's last (now deleted) comment above, reporting and supporting (in russian) Lavrov's propaganda was really intolerable. I shall "move on" indeed, but my heart bleeds.

Answer (score 2):

So this is the typical $1^\infty$ type-limit. To find the limit I always start by adding and subtracting $1$ inside the parenthesis (you are "apparentlly" doing nothing), like so $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\Bigg(1-1+\frac{x^5+\pi x^4+e}{x^5+e x^4+\pi}\Bigg)^x=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\Bigg(1+\frac{(\pi-e)(x^4-1)}{x^5+e x^4+\pi}\Bigg)^x=(\star)$$
Since we know that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}(1+\frac{1}{x})^x=e$, our priority is to set our limit in a similar way.
$$(\star)=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\Bigg(1+\frac{1}{\frac{x^5+e x^4+\pi}{(\pi-e)(x^4-1)}}\Bigg)^x=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\Bigg(\Bigg[1+\frac{1}{\frac{x^5+e x^4+\pi}{(\pi-e)(x^4-1)}}\Bigg]^{\frac{x^5+e x^4+\pi}{(\pi-e)(x^4-1)}}\Bigg)^{x\cdot\frac{(\pi-e)(x^4-1)}{x^5+e x^4+\pi}}$$
Please go ahead and see by yourself that this last limit is equal to the first one you gave. If not, trust me. Now, we know that the part inside the parenthesis converges to $e$ $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\Bigg[1+\frac{1}{\frac{x^5+e x^4+\pi}{(\pi-e)(x^4-1)}}\Bigg]^{\frac{x^5+e x^4+\pi}{(\pi-e)(x^4-1)}}=e$$ and our exponent converges to $\pi-e$ since $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}x\cdot\frac{(e-\pi)(x^4-1)}{x^5+e x^4+\pi}=\pi-e$$
And so the limit is $e^{\pi-e}$. If you found this answer helpful please flag it as a correct answer. Thanks!!

Comment: Каким является окончательный ответ к текущей проблеме: $e^{\pi-e}$ или ${\pi-e}$?

Comment: @VadimChernetsov $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac {x^5+\pi x^4+e}{x^5+ex^4+\pi}\right)^x = e^{\pi-e}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac {1+\frac {1}{x}\pi+\frac {1}{x^5}e}{1+\frac {1}{x}e+\frac {1}{x^5}\pi}\right)^x$$
Arrived at this point, you can use geometric series:
$$\left(\frac {1+\frac {1}{x}\pi+\frac {1}{x^5}e}{1+\frac {1}{x}e+\frac {1}{x^5}\pi}\right)^x\sim\left(\left(1+\frac {1}{x}\pi+\frac {1}{x^5}e\right)\left(1-\frac {1}{x}e-\frac {1}{x^5}\pi \right)\right)^x\sim \left(1 +\frac{\pi-e}{x}\right)^x \to e^{\pi-e}$$

Comment: Each step would require some justification. $\sim$ has a precise meaning and the final $\to$ is certainly far from obvious to the OP.

Comment: @AnneBauval the last limit isn't known since high school? $\lim_{x \to \infty}(1+a/x)^x=e^a$. I have been taught to use $\sim$ to bypass  the little-o notation, but they are equivalent, if the approximation is correct. So i considered only the terms $1/x$. Is it wrong?

Comment: It *used to* be known... :-( As for $\sim$, it is *not* equivalent to little-o notation. For $f(x)^x$ to be $\sim g(x)^x,$ it is not sufficient that $f(x)\sim g(x).$ You must *prove* that $x\ln\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\to0$ (for each of your steps).